# Asking for reference in the same phone interview email

Tags: interviewing, references

I applied for a job and four weeks later I received an email from my potential employer, asking me if I was available for a phone interview and also to provide reference.I replied that I was available and sent 3 references.Week later one of my reference told me he received a call from my potential employer. Now two weeks later I am still waiting for their phone interview.Is this even normal?

Comment: How do you even know the call was real? :)

Comment: Maybe next time tell the potential employer you're happy for them to call your references after an interview if you're a prospective candidate. I'm not sure what country you're in, in Australia this isn't normal. In the GFC I had to provide a list of referee's only to be called if I got past the employers interviews. Otherwise, I don't provide them until asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Did you schedule a date and time for the phone interview?  That should have been your first step before providing any references.

Comment: Honestly, I was so excited to get an email back from one company after sending so many appliactions that I didn't think this through and I thought not sending references may not be good for me .

Comment: I think you need to proactive communicate to your protential employer at the moment, ask them any progress update. Generally, if to this stage, they will proactive tell you if they decide not to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that could be happening. First, the employer might be busy with other things. Second, a bad scenario, the employer might not be interested in the job position for you. Third, the employer might not be pleased or interested in the reference. Only the first case is good.

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal.  Reference checks are the last stage of interviewing in every process I've ever taken part of. Generally done right before an offer is made, sometimes after a conditional offer is made.  Not when scheduling a phone interview.  I don't see anything likely to be nefarious here, just odd.  I wouldn't give any company my references until after I've done an in person (or zoom equivalent).  Quite frankly I don't want my references bothered unless I think this is a done deal, I definitely don't want them bothered for every introductory phone call I take.

Comment: I just had a contact where the third-party recruiter did check the references before even showing my resume to the potential employer. I never saw that before, but it's not unheard of, at least since last monday.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is normal.  They aren’t in a rush clearly, but if you care you could call them once a week or so to find out progress.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!